# vaadin slow UI when loading MYSQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, vaadin

I have a client vaadin app that use in-memory DB and I added the possibility to switch to mysql.  I use the backend as an API. All operations using those mysql method instead of the in memory DB take so much time (at least 30s each) on client side but are still instantaneous on mysql side.

```
public SingletonGraph updateGraph (boolean isMySQL){
    g = null;
    if (isMySQL) {
        fixGraphData(new MySQLGraph(connection));
        g.setMysql(true);
    } else {
        fixGraphDataMem(new MemGraph());
        g.setMysql(false);
    }
    return g;
}

private synchronized static void fixGraphData(Graph graph) {
    try {
            g = new SingletonGraph(new PAP(
                    new GraphAdmin(graph),
                    new ProhibitionsAdmin(new MySQLProhibitions(connection)),
                    new ObligationsAdmin(new MemObligations())
            ));
        System.out.println("MySQLGraph");
        superContext = null;
        activePCs = new HashSet<>();

        for (Node n : graph.getNodes()) {
                if (n.getProperties().get("namespace") != null && n.getProperties().get("namespace").equals("super")) {
                    switch (n.getType()) {
                        case OA:
                            System.out.println("Super OA: " + n.getName());
                            superOAId = n.getName();
                            break;
                        case UA:
                            if (n.getName().equals("super_ua2")) {
                                System.out.println("Super UA: " + n.getName());
                                superUAId = n.getName();
                            }
                            break;
                        case U:
                            System.out.println("Super U: " + n.getName());
                            superContext = new UserContext(n.getName(), rand.toString());
                            break;
                        case PC:
                            System.out.println("Super PC: " + n.getName());
                            superPCId = n.getName();
                            break;
                }
           }

            if (n.getType().equals(NodeType.PC)) {
                activePCs.add(new PolicyClassWithActive(n));
            }
        }

        OperationSet resourceOps = new OperationSet();
        resourceOps.add(Operations.READ);
        resourceOps.add(Operations.WRITE);
        resourceOps.add(Operations.OBJECT_ACCESS);
        getPDP().setResourceOps(resourceOps);

    } catch (PMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I read that it is a common issue on Vaadin that using mysql somehow slow the UI and that some vaadin method favors a lazy loading however even using those specific method I have no idea how to optimize the client side. Has anyone ever experiment that ? How to optimize it ?

Thank you.

Ps : I use synchronized static as I only want one instance of the graph in my project.

Comment: The UI doesn't care if you use an in-memory database or MySQL, it will only be slower with MySQL if the DB operations are slower with MySQL, if the data returned is the same.

Comment: Additional information request from the MySQL server. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @ErikLumme well the thing is that all the operations run instantaneously on MySQL but it takes several minutes for the UI to render it ...

Comment: @WilsonHauck I will send you the link tomorrow, thank you for answering .

Comment: @Sox- then I assume the MySQL DB returns magnitudes more data than the in-memory database did? In that case, the problem is in the amount of data, not the type of database.

Comment: Which vaadin version are we talking about here? It could be that you fetch all Data from DB into a `ListDataProvider` meaning *all loaded items are now in memory*. If you indeed have more data now than before, this could indeed lead to very slow UI. If you use a ListDataProvider, maybe switch to using [CallbackDataProvider](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples) (example "Grid with lazy loading")) which will actually lazy load the items that need to be displayed, instead of loading them all into memory.

Comment: @WilsonHauck https://pastebin.com/qygYaBBg

Comment: @ErikLumme It retrieves exactly the same data. The only reason I decided to use MySQL is to be able to store what the In Memory could not.

Comment: @kscherrer I use [HierarchicalDataProvider](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/13.0.11/com/vaadin/flow/data/provider/hierarchy/class-use/HierarchicalDataProvider.html) and Vaadin 13

Comment: @Sox- Need - Additional information request from the MySQL server. RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini being used today.  Are you using MacOs?

Comment: Hi Wilson, yes I am on Mac, I dont have any my.cnf or my.ini. I dont really think my issue is linked to MySQL engine or server but more to my own code.

Comment: @Sox- Since you do not have or can not find my.cnf or my.ini on the server providing the MySQL data, there is no point in analyzing your data to provide suggestions you can not implement.  Please view profile, Network profile for contact info if you would like assistance with finding your configuration files to allow response time improvement.